# 405 Method Not Allowed - Strapi Custom Plugin

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm developing a Strapi Plugin that will contain 2 POST routes as `/create-payment-intent` and `/confirm-payment-intent` but my tests using Insomnia are always returning the error 405 Method Not Allowed.

I have no issues when starting the Strapi server (`yarn develop` && `yarn build`). I've tried different approachs but nothing has fixed it.

Follow my `src\plugins\payment\server\routes\index.ts`:

```
const paymentRoutes = [
  {
    method: "POST",
    path: "/create-payment-intent",
    handler: "paymentController.createPaymentIntent",
    config: {
      auth: true,
      policies: [],
    },
  },
  {
    method: "POST",
    path: "/confirm-payment-intent",
    handler: "paymentController.confirmPaymentIntent",
    config: {
      auth: true,
      policies: [],
    },
  },
];

export default paymentRoutes;
```

and `config\plugins.js`:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    // ...
    'payment': {
        enabled: true,
        resolve: './src/plugins/payment',
    },
});
```

The routes I'm trying to reach are:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1337/v1/payment/create-payment-intent
http://127.0.0.1:1337/v1/payment/confirm-payment-intent
```

I'm using API Token generated in Strapi admin with full acess, so I don't need to give permission to them, I guess.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong please? Thank you!

Comment: Hi you routes config is incorrect, you can look here https://github.com/antokhio/strapi-plugin-categorizer/tree/main/server/routes

Comment: To debug you can use `yarn strapi routes:list`